# Make 3 columns equal height in viewport with nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav bar that is 70px, under the nav bar I will have 3 columns stacked on top of each other.  Im trying to figure out a way to make the columns all of equal height.  Basically something like:

```
height: calc((100vh-70px)/3);
```

I don't think this works, any solutions similar to this?

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
   </ul>
 </nav>

 <div id="workTop">
     <div class="one_third column workSquare"></div>
      <div class="one_third column workSquare2"></div>
      <div class="one_third column workSquare"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you do something like : `height: 300px`

Comment: I want it to be responsive

Comment: You can totally do responsive design on height, @madalinivascu. It's a good idea.

Comment: This is the third post I've reviewed in the last 30 minutes with negativity. What's up with people tonight?

Comment: @madalinivascu If i want all columns to to fit equally on varying screen sizes(heights) then I have to take height into consideration.  Who taught you responsive design?

Comment: "I don't think this works" can you make a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: @madalinivascu Taking height into consideration is not a bad idea, you might need to think a little harder. :)

Comment: @SailorJerry there are 2 possibilities of going wrong with your idea : 1. have the height of content  smaller than the calculated height which creates white space (bad for ux), 2. your content height is larger than the calculated height  you will ether have multiple scrolls or you will need to cut the content down which is even badder for ux

Comment: @madalinivascu even badder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calc() should work for what you are trying to do, note that by [calc() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) + and - operators must be surrounded by whitespace.

> **Note:** The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.
>   The operand of calc(50% -8px) for instance will be parsed as a
>   percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while
>   the operand of calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a minus
>   sign and a length. Even further, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a
>   length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage. The * and /
>   operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is
>   allowed, and recommended.

so change your height to

```
height: calc((100vh - 70px)/3);
```

Comment: You should be aware, if you're going to use calc that it isn't supported, at this time, in many android mobile browsers, and only has partial support for modern android mobile browsers. Also, it has zero support for opera mini. You can visit http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be responsive then you can use media queries to account for different screen sizes. Or, use Bootstrap or some other grid system.

If your goal is to change the size of the columns when the screen changes size then you can use something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.column').css("height", $(window).height() / 3);
});
```

Obviously this doesn't account for the nav but you get the idea.

#### Edit:

@gyre pointed out we should focus on CSS so here's an expanded option.

If you are wanting the columns to always stretch from the top to the bottom, then you can use percentages and mix them with media queries to approximate the desired balance across sizes. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .column{
        height: 85%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){
    .column{
        height: 95%;
     }
}
```

This will however, only make the column 85% of the parent element. So you should account for that.

Comment: There should be a way to do this in CSS, though, shouldn't there?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned the media queries first. But the OP didn't specify so I'm giving a range of options

Comment: wouldn't this  `$('.column').css("height", ($(window).height()-70) / 3);` work with the nav?

Comment: Yes, but then your style is directly coupled to the function. If the nav changes the OP will have to keep track of this

Comment: then he should do something like `$('.column').css("height", ($(window).height()-$('nav').height()) / 3);`